# Usage of intonation with sentence ending particles e.g. ね

Tags: intonation

[*Negotiation of Contingent Talk: The Japanese Interactional Particles Ne and Sa*, page 44](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FbVGxqAx5jwC&pg=PA44&dq=japanese%20ne%20intonation&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CcS2VNHAO4eGywOKu4DoCA&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=japanese%20ne%20intonation&f=false)

For example the above link says that there are various different intonations e.g. rising, rise-fall,fall-rise etc that all correspond to different functions, but I can't seem to find any audio samples that clearly show what these sound like.

Can anyone explain what I should be hearing and where, or provide some audio samples for the different categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think many Japanese learning resources cover it, for the intonation studies are still in its earliest stage, as far as I know. I'm not an expert in Japanese intonation either, but it's fairly easy to show the difference in my own voice.

https://clyp.it/qa2xdoip

It says in the following order:

> いいね (rising) "Sounds good."
>
> いいね (fall-rise) "You hear me?"
>
> いいね (rise-fall) "Fantastic!"

P.S.
The Japanese translation of "Like!" in Facebook is いいね！, which I think is pronounced like the first one if you do.